# How to .htaccess redirect file name to be url parameters on new domain?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to be able to redirect url such as `subdomain.domain.com/426/long-tail-kw.html` to new domain and url such as `differentdomain.com/goodname.php?id=long-tail-kw`

Also, the number in the url `426` will change often, it could also be `1` or whatever number up to `500`

How can I do this in .htaccess file?

Also, the redirect must work with this code that sends the people who come from bing ONLY to the new url. If a person just enters the url then he will not be redirected but when he comes from bing or from whatever specified referrer then he will be redirected.

Thus far I have this code that I used for my old site that had `cat-x` in the url but I don't know how to change the code to work with only a number in the url instead of `cat-x`

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (bing)
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?server10\.olddomain\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^cat-\d+/(.+?)\.html$ http://newdomain.com/go.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,R=302]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `cat-` part:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (bing)
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?server10\.olddomain\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^\d+/(.+?)\.html$ http://newdomain.com/go.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,R=302]
```